# Problem with resizing of DatePicker in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, datepicker, android-jetpack-compose

I am making an Android application with Kotlin and Jetpack Compose. I'm currently stuck with making a DatePicker. The goal is to have the date picker calendar appear on the app screen itself, rather than as a dialog box. But, once I try to run the app on a smaller phone, the calendar overlaps the dates on it and they are not visible.

At the moment this is the code for date picker:

```
Column(
          modifier = Modifier
              .fillMaxWidth()
              .padding(8.dp),
          horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
      )
      {
          DatePicker(
              state = datePickerState,
              showModeToggle = false,
              modifier = modifier,
              title = null,
          )
      }
```

And when I call the composable function for the date picker I call it like this:

```
DatePickerView(
                  selectedDate,
                  onDateSelected = {
                      selectedDate = it
                      formattedDate = convertMillisToDate(it)
                  },
                  modifier = Modifier
                      .fillMaxWidth()
                      .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
                      .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
              )
```

On bigger screens everything is fine, but on smaller screens this problem comes. How can I dynamically resize the date picker, based on screen size?

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically resize the DatePicker based on the screen size in a Jetpack Compose application, you can use the LocalConfiguration and LocalDensity providers to get information about the screen size and density. Then, you can adjust the size of your DatePicker accordingly.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun DatePickerScreen() {
  
    val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
    val screenWidthDp = configuration.screenWidthDp

    val datePickerWidth = (screenWidthDp * 0.8).dp

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(8.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        
        DatePickerView(
            selectedDate = System.currentTimeMillis(),
            onDateSelected = { /* Handle date selection */ },
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
                .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
                .width(datePickerWidth)
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun DatePickerView(
    selectedDate: Long,
    onDateSelected: (Long) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    val datePickerState = rememberDatePickerState(selectedDate)

    DatePicker(
        state = datePickerState,
        showModeToggle = false,
        modifier = modifier,
        title = null,
    )
}
```